# Problemas al acceder a web de Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Estoy iniciándome en Spring WEB y tengo problemas al lograr acceder a la página una vez está el servidor Tomcat iniciado. He probado tanto en Windows como una máquina virtual Linux a ejecutar el JAR y acceder remotamente a la web pero en ambos casos no logro acceder con éxito, no obstante de manera local si que lo consigo.

[image: Programa ejecutado]

Comment: QUé quieres decir con `De manera local` y remotamente? No está claro qué es lo que estás intentando ni cómo

Answer (score 1):

EL mensaje indica que el servicio esta iniciado y escuchando en el puerto 8080, asi que accediendo desde esa misma maquina a http://localhost:8080/ deberia resultar.

Si deseas acceder desde la maquina host (la que arranco la maquina virtual), debes saber cual es la direccion IP interna de dicha maquina, ejecutando en la maquina virtual (te indicara las IPs que tiene asignadas):

```
ifconfig | grep inet
```

Utiliza la ip que sea de tipo red local (alguna que comienze por 192.168.x.x o 10.0.x.x o alguna de ese tipo, y luego de obtenerla, accede al servidor usando `http://10.0.0.2:8080/` (suponiendo que la IP fuera esa)

SI por alguna razon no puedes acceder a ningun servicio de dicha maquina virtual puede que no este configurada la red para conectarse con el equipo host (modo solo local por ejemplo) o alguna regla de firewall impide acceder al servicio de otra ubicacion distinta a localhost.

Comment: Intento acceder desde la IP externa. Están los puertos abiertos a esta misma. Accediendo de forma interna como tu dices no tengo ningún problema.

Gracias por la respuesta ;)